# Getting data from external javascript file to Angular 4 project

Tags: javascript, angular

Im facing an issue with accessing a data outside of Angular project.
Im using Openlayers map, which has functions inside external js file.
(./assets/settings.js). And I need to get a variable from that file to Angular variable. Is there any other way than just copying the full settings.js code to angular? I tried pushing the variable to div and text input with innerHTML, and reading the value in Angular, but to get it working that way, I couldn't automate it, and only worked by adding a extra button where I had to bind the function to get data.

This needs to work as following: On clicking the map (svg format - cant add eventlistener) there are markers, which on click should display the location data. On clicking the marker an http request is sent with location id as a paremeter, which should come from that Javascript file.

I hope I managed to explain the problem well and maybe someone has a solution.

Thanks

Comment: can you show some relevant code?

Comment: there really isn't any relevant code that would help to understand the problem. The main issue is getting variable value from (location relative to /app folder) ../assets/settings.js to /app/home/home.component.ts

Comment: are you using angular/cli? or custom webpack?

Comment: angular cli, sorry forgot to mention that